# Rspec capybara Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError could not be scrolled into view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec

I have this test spec:

```
Scenario "preview offer", js: true do
    ...

    When "I click onto the contact details tab" do
      within_frame "preview-iframe" do
        click_link "Enter details"
      end
    end
    ...
end
```

But it throws an exception:

```
Failures:

  1) Preview Offer preview coaching offer booking with Journeyman enabled
     Failure/Error: button.click

     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError:
       Element <a href="/offers/details"> could not be scrolled into view
```

The actual html is:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="preview-iframe" name="preview-iframe" scrolling="no" src="/offer">
    ...
        <ul class="list-steps">
            ...
            <li data-page="enter-details">
              <a href="/offers/details">Enter details</a>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
    ...
</iframe>
```

I have try to be more specific for the test case as:

```
When "I click onto the contact details tab" do
  sleep 5
  execute_script "window.scrollBy(0,500)"
  within_frame "preview-iframe" do
    button = find("#body > div > header > div > div.header__bar > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a")
    button.click
  end
end
```

- I added `sleep 5` because to give times to iframe content to be fully loaded
- added scroll to ensure the page is scrollable to the view?
- specified the button to be click

But still got the same error, I use selenium as the web driver, anyone has this issue?

thank you

Comment: Tthe "scrolling=no" attribute is suspect -- it's a really old/deprecated HTML feature but may be stopping the content from being scrollable into view on the window size you're testing with (or just pause the test at that point).  Open the site in whatever browser you're configuring selenium to use at the window size you're testing with and see if you can actually scroll the content into view.  Only solution may be to resize the window when testing.  Also - you REALLY want to stop using CSS selectors that are that specific in tests -- it makes them VERY brittle

Comment: already remove the attribute, but still no luck

Comment: did you try it manually? Did you try increasing the window size?